# Spin Configuration of Active Space in PySCF

Tags: pyscf, spin, casscf

I was running a state averaged CASSCF (4,4) calculation for the first 3 roots of the TMM biradical in PySCF. I wanted to get the spin configuration of the active space but the only information I could find in the simulation output is the following table.

```
** Largest CI components **
  [alpha occ-orbitals] [beta occ-orbitals]  state 0   CI coefficient
  [0 1]                [0 2]                           0.680999601372
  [0 2]                [0 1]                          -0.680999601372
  [1 2]                [0 3]                           0.162876965573
  [0 3]                [1 2]                          -0.162876965573
  [alpha occ-orbitals] [beta occ-orbitals]  state 1   CI coefficient
  [0 1]                [0 1]                           0.521598297554
  [0 1]                [0 2]                          -0.296126060144
  [0 1]                [1 2]                          -0.235407708465
  [0 1]                [0 3]                          -0.106906206218
  [0 2]                [0 1]                          -0.296126060144
  [0 2]                [0 2]                          -0.521414937085
  [0 2]                [1 2]                          -0.133788127011
  [0 2]                [0 3]                           0.190214831302
  [1 2]                [0 1]                          -0.235407708465
  [1 2]                [0 2]                          -0.133788127011
  [0 3]                [0 1]                          -0.106906206218
  [0 3]                [0 2]                           0.190214831302
  [alpha occ-orbitals] [beta occ-orbitals]  state 2   CI coefficient
  [0 1]                [0 1]                           0.275144934363
  [0 1]                [0 2]                           0.518472331429
  [0 1]                [1 2]                          -0.131745811887
  [0 1]                [0 3]                           0.201009810870
  [0 2]                [0 1]                           0.518472331429
  [0 2]                [0 2]                          -0.313130614232
  [0 2]                [1 2]                           0.232139108556
  [0 2]                [0 3]                           0.115309844670
  [1 2]                [0 1]                          -0.131745811887
  [1 2]                [0 2]                           0.232139108556
  [0 3]                [0 1]                           0.201009810870
  [0 3]                [0 2]                           0.115309844670
```

I had previously posted a question on the interpretation of this table at [Table of Largest CI Components in PySCF CASSCF Calculation](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/11824/table-of-largest-ci-components-in-pyscf-casscf-calculation) where I came to know that the ground state (state 0) in the table represents an open-shell singlet state. But according to the <S**2> value provided in the output, the ground state is supposed to be a triplet state

```
CASSCF energy = -154.937807129837
CASCI E = -154.937807129837  E(CI) = -3.22262432727504  S^2 = 0.6666667
CASCI state-averaged energy = -154.937807129837
CASCI energy for each state
  State 0 weight 0.333333  E = -154.964945548567 S^2 = 2.0000000
  State 1 weight 0.333333  E = -154.924749463197 S^2 = 0.0000000
  State 2 weight 0.333333  E = -154.923726377748 S^2 = 0.0000000
```

Why is there a disagreement in the result? Is there an alternative approach to obtaining the spin configuration of the active space in PySCF?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

PySCF works in a determinant basis. This means that you can only set the value of $S_z$, the $z$ projection of the total spin.

If you have a state with total spin $S$, it will have $z$ projections of $-S$, $-S+1$, $\dots$, $S-1$, and $S$. This means that if you try to target a singlet state by setting $S_z=0$, you may also find that the lowest root is a higher spin state, such as a triplet, quintet, heptet, etc.

The energy ordering of the states depends on many factors. The used orbitals are one important factor. The size of the active space and dynamical correlation is another: going to a larger active space or including dynamic correlation can change or flip the ordering of the various spin states. This is likely what you are also seeing.

Furthermore, in this case, you have a small active space and you are not optimizing the orbitals for the ground state, but rather for a state average. The orbitals may simply be better for the excited triplet state than for the ground singlet state, which results in the incorrect ordering.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I don't understand what you mean by "orbitals may simply be better for the excited triplet state than for the ground singlet state". Could you explain? Also, I have edited the question as I believe I was not being specific

Comment: You are optimizing the orbitals for the average energy of the three lowest roots. The orbitals will therefore not yield the lowest possible value for the energy of the lowest root.